# Code only working the first time round?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in this project I have a div that displays images when clicked. I have a transition attached to this so that the images fade in. In my jQuery, I have a function that does this and also I have added the functionality that the "onclick" event is disabled until the transition ends. This works, but only the first time. Any additional time that the function is called, if you double click, the image changes without waiting for the end of the transition. I am puzzled as to why. Any help appreciated.

Here is the relevant code:

html:

```
 <div id="rightWindow" style="background-image: url('Images/<?php echo $randomPic; ?>');"


  onclick="

    var enable = function() { counter++;

    if (counter > 7) {counter = 1;}

    $( '#rightWindow' ).css('background-image', 'url(Images/<?php

      echo $substring;

     ?>' + counter + '.jpg)');}

    enable();

    this.onclick = null;

    $( '#rightWindow' ).on('transitionend',
        function(e) {

        alert('ended!');

        this.onclick = enable;

      });


   "></div>
```

Comment: this.onclick should be function call like function() {}. Not boolean value.

Comment: @bigless `onclick` is nowhere a boolean.

Comment: right. really dunno where I explored it..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be useful:

I got this example on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/event_transitionend.asp)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

#myDIV:hover {
    width: 400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV">hola mundo</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myDiv").on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd', function () {

      // your logic, transition is run

  });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```